# Ruby on rails facebook login has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a sample app using ROR. I have used **has_secure_password** to store the user's password when a user signs up.

Now I am using **Omniauth** for facebook login. I read that **password_digest** cannot be left   blank. So now I want to store the password in the encrypted format same as has_secure_password. How can I do that?

Right now I am storing the password hard-coded as "test".

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
def facebook_login
      auth_hash = request.env['omniauth.auth']
        email=auth_hash.info.email
        @user_email=User.find_by_email(email)
          if @user_email
          render @user_email
          else     
                  @user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
                  redirect_to root_url
      end

    end
```

**user.rb**

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:outh_provider, :fb_id)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.outh_provider = auth.provider
      user.fb_id = auth.uid
      user.name=auth.info.name
      user.email=auth.info.email
      user.password_digest="test"
      user.fb_username = auth.info.name
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!(validate: false)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't set the password_digest directly, you set the password and password_confirmation fields (to the same value) and then has_secure_password does it's magic and fills the password_digest field when the user is saved.